# what is VB default property in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Found an example and I can't understand what it means.

[How can I read from a DataRow or a DataReader using the same code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666943/how-can-i-read-from-a-datarow-or-a-datareader-using-the-same-code)

I have no idea how to convert the interface and two classes in answer to C#?

Edit: Here is the code that I want to convert to C#:

```
Interface IIndexer
    Default ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As String)
End Interface

Class DataReaderWrapper
Implements IIndexer

Private ReadOnly _reader As IDataReader

Public Sub New(reader As IDataReader)
    _reader = reader
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As String) As Object Implements IIndexer.Item
    Get
        Return _reader(index)
    End Get
End Property
End Class

Class DataRowWrapper
Implements IIndexer

Private ReadOnly _row As DataRow

Public Sub New(row As DataRow)
    _row = row
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As String) As Object Implements IIndexer.Item
    Get
        Return _row(index)
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: There is no analogue in C# for the VB.NET default property.

Comment: Matti what are you trying to convert.. why not paste the code here that of which you are trying to convert or want converted..

Comment: This should "answer" the problem with the `default` property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih - A default value on an auto-property is not the same as a default property of a type.

Comment: Any reason you can't compile this code in a VB.NET project and reference it in C#?

Comment: @Oded: The code should be readable by humans.

Comment: I didn't realize VB.NET wasn't human readable.

Comment: @Oded I used to code in VB6, then in VB.net for some years, Now I just can't stand it.

Comment: @HighCore - That's neither here nor there in regards to this question. You _can_ read and understand it, right?

Comment: At 1st glance this VB-thing makes no sense whatsoever. How typing "End Property" can be better than "}" ?

Comment: @Oded yep, hes asking about `indexers` in C#, which are somewhat reminiscent of the default properties in VB.Net

Comment: FYI Joel and the gang and I will be discussing VB default properties and many other subjects in podcast #45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, as far as I know, no equivalent. More information about the [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/371ww4fs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword can be found at MSDN.

What you are seeing here is an [Indexer in an Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkyhsw31%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The converted code would be something like the following:

```
interface IIndexer
{
    object this[string index] { get; }
}

class DataReaderWrapper : IIndexer
{
    private readonly IDataReader _reader;
    public DataReaderWrapper(IDataReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public object this[string index]
    {
        get { return _reader[index]; }
    }
}

class DataRowWrapper : IIndexer
{
    private readonly DataRow _row;
    public DataRowWrapper(DataRow row)
    {
        _row = row;
    }

    public object this[string index]
    {
        get { return _row[index]; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks something I need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, it's unclear what you mean by 'default property':

```
var loadedItems = new List<Item>();
SqlDataReader dr = GetItemsDataReader();
while(dr.Read()){
  Item item = GetItemFromData(dr);
  loadedItems.Add(item);
}

private Item GetItemFromData(SqlDataReader dr){
  var loadedItem = new Item();
  loadedItem.ID = dr["ID"];
  loadedItem.Name = dr["Name"];
  'etc., etc.'
  Return loadedItem
}
```

Comment: I mean: Default ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As String)

Comment: @Oded: in examples I found in web they always have type like As Interger int the end but the interface's Item has not.

Comment: I guess the C# equivalent would be `private Item this[int idx] { get { ... } }`

Comment: thanks Echilon. I try to fit this information to the rest of the example.